# Concurrency Visualizer in VisualStudio 2015 not loading the Symbols

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

I have a very basic MFC program created with VS2015. When I create CVtrace file, in a system where VS is installed, I can browse to the source. On the other hand if I capture trace on a target system, for the same exe, where no VS is installed , the symbols belonging to the exe are not loaded.

On the Target system the CVCollectionCmd is used to capture the Trace and then the trace files are moved to the release folder(where the exe and pdb files are present) in the source system and subsequently opened in Visual studio. Any hint would be helpful. Both source and target systems are windows 7. 
Any hint would be great.
Thanks in advance!